# How to decode ASN.1 to XML with erlang

Tags: xml, erlang, asn.1

I use asn1 module in erlang to decode. The output is like

```
{'UL-CCCH-Message',asn1_NOVALUE,
               {rrcConnectionRequest,
                {'RRCConnectionRequest',
                 {'tmsi-and-LAI',
                  {'TMSI-and-LAI-GSM-MAP',
                   [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,
                    1,1,0,1,0],
                   {'LAI',
                    {'PLMN-Identity',[2,2,6],[0,1]},
                    [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1]}}},
                 terminatingBackgroundCall,noError,
                 {'MeasuredResultsOnRACH',
                  {'MeasuredResultsOnRACH_currentCell',
                   {fdd,
                    {'MeasuredResultsOnRACH_currentCell_modeSpecificInfo_fdd',
                     {'cpich-Ec-N0',39}}}},
                  asn1_NOVALUE},
                 asn1_NOVALUE}}}
```

How can I output XML instead of erlang term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that any erlang term (not specific to the asn.1 module) could be output as XML easily by a function like this:

```
to_xml(X) when is_atom(X) ->
    "<atom>" ++ atom_to_list(X) ++ "</atom>"; % might want apostrophes
to_xml(X) when is_integer(X) ->
    "<integer>" ++ io_lib:format("~p", [X]) ++ "</integer>";
to_xml(X) when is_tuple(X) ->
    "<tuple size=" ++ tuple_size(X) ++ ">" ++ % or maybe want size implicit
        lists:foldr(fun(E, L) -> to_xml(E) ++ L end, [], tuple_to_list(X))
        ++ "</tuple>";
to_xml(X) when is_list(X) ->
    "<list>" ++ lists:foldr(fun(E, L) -> to_xml(E) ++ L end, [], X) ++ "</list>";
% etc...
```

Comment: Thanks your answer. I wrote a function like this but using record name for xml tag. For example "{'PLMN-Identity',[2,2,6],[0,1]}" ==> "<PLMN-Identity><value>2,2,6</value><value>0,1</value></PLMN-Identity>". Now I am trying to replace "<value></value>" with record field name.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps two available option for you for converting ASN1 to XML representation:

http://www.research.ibm.com/trl/projects/xml/xss4j/docs/axt-readme.html

http://www.obj-sys.com/webtools/asn2xml.php